# How do I read the contents of a new cloud storage file of type .json from within a cloud function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

The `event` passed to my Google cloud function only really tells me the name of the bucket and file, and whether the file was deleted. Yes, there's more there, but it doesn't seem all that useful:

```
{ timestamp: '2017-03-25T07:13:40.293Z', 
eventType: 'providers/cloud.storage/eventTypes/object.change', 
resource: 'projects/_/buckets/my-echo-bucket/objects/base.json#1490426020293545', 
data: { kind: 'storage#object', 
       resourceState: 'exists', 
       id: 'my-echo-bucket/base.json/1490426020293545', 
       selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-echo-bucket/o/base.json', 
       name: 'base.json', 
       bucket: 'my-echo-bucket', 
       generation: '1490426020293545', 
       metageneration: '1', 
       contentType: 'application/json', 
       timeCreated: '2017-03-25T07:13:40.185Z', 
       updated: '2017-03-25T07:13:40.185Z', 
       storageClass: 'STANDARD', 
       size: '548', 
       md5Hash: 'YzE3ZjUyZjlkNDU5YWZiNDg2NWI0YTEyZWZhYzQyZjY=', 
       mediaLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-echo-bucket/o/base.json?generation=1490426020293545&alt=media', contentLanguage: 'en', crc32c: 'BQDL9w==' } 
}
```

How do I get the **contents** and not merely the meta-data of a new .json file uploaded to a gs bucket?

I tried using `npm:request()` on `event.data.selfLink`, which is a URL for the file in the storage bucket, and got back an authorization error:

`"code": 401, "message": "Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object my-echo-bucket/base.json."`

There was a similar question on SO about reading storage buckets, but probably on a different platform. Anyway it was **unanswered**:

[How do I read the contents of a file on Google Cloud Storage using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093528/how-do-i-read-the-contents-of-a-file-on-google-cloud-storage-using-javascript)
`

Comment: Note: This is a [self answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Hopefully, others find it useful.  If you have a better/cleaner/shorter answer, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a client library for google storage instead of accessing via the URL. Using `request()` against the URL would only work if the file was exposed to public access.

Import the google cloud storage library in the npm-managed directory containing your project.

```
npm i @google-cloud/storage -S
```

The [npm page for google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) has decent examples but I had to read through the API a bit to see an easy way to download to memory.

Within the Google Cloud Functions environment, you do not need to supply any api key, etc. to storage as initialization.

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
```

The metadata passed about the file can be used to determine if you really want the file or not.

When you want the file, you can download it with the [file.download](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.8.0/storage/file?method=download) function, which can take either a callback or, lacking a callback, will return a promise.
The data however, is returned as a `Buffer` so you will need to call `data.toString('utf-8')` to convert it to a utf-8 encoded string.

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

exports.logNewJSONFiles = function logNewJSONFiles(event){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const file = event.data;
        if (!file){
            console.log("not a file event");
            return resolve();
        }
        if (file.resourceState === 'not_exists'){
            console.log("file deletion event");
            return resolve();
        }
        if (file.contentType !== 'application/json'){
            console.log("not a json file");
            return resolve();
        }
        if (!file.bucket){
            console.log("bucket not provided");
            return resolve();
        }
        if (!file.name){
            console.log("file name not provided");
            return resolve();
        }
        (storage
         .bucket(file.bucket)
         .file(file.name)
         .download()
         .then(function(data){
             if (data)
                 return data.toString('utf-8');
         })
         .then(function(data){
             if (data) {
                 console.log("new file "+file.name);
                 console.log(data);
                 resolve(data);
             }
         })
         .catch(function(e){ reject(e); })
             );
    });
};
```

Deployment is as expected:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy logNewJSONFiles --stage-bucket gs://my-stage-bucket --trigger-bucket gs://my-echo-bucket
```

Remember to look in the Stackdriver:Logging page on Google Cloud Platform for the `console.log` entries.

**UPDATE:** (2019) When cloud-functions first released, they had some issues with `ECONNRESET`.  I think that's fixed now.  If not, use something like `npm:promise-retry`

Comment: +1 on fixing the ECONNRESET errors. I have to force my cron function to retry several times a day in order to ensure it will write to all of the files properly.

Answer (score 6):

```
npm install @google-cloud/storage --production
```

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

You should achieve that `npm ls` shows no errors like `npm ERR! missing:`.

app.js:

```
...

  const storage = require("@google-cloud/storage")();
  storage.
    bucket("mybucket").
    file("myfile.txt").
    download( function(err, contents) {
      console.log(contents.toString());
    } );
```